# What's a consistent way of obtain AppSettings that accounts for applicationHost.config?

Tags: configuration, iis-7, appsettings

So, appSettings can be set in app.config, web.config, machine,config... But, when you work under IIS 7 you can also have appSettings being applied under applicationHost.config with a specific carve out for your site.  So, what's a consistent way for me to know what AppSettings I should be using???

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager is fine if this is a client profile.
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager if this is a web-app ... well, maybe.
Microsoft.Web.Administration if I expect values in applicationHosting.config - ouch ... and even then they don't roll-up hierarchically so it seems that you're left holding that process.

Does anyone have a consistent approach to processing AppSettings that accounts for applicationHost.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually specify `<appSettings>` in your `applicationHost.config` file. This is because `applicationHost.config` defines settings specific to IIS only. You can review the `applicationHost.config` schema to confirm this:

> `%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml`

If you try to edit `applicationHost.config` and add an `<appSetting>` section to a site or under a `<location path="...">` section you will get an error (IIS may not start and IIS MMC console will display a configuration error).

If you configure a global application setting in IIS manager this actually gets configured in the master `web.config` file that matches the default .NET Framework version setting in IIS.

`<appSettings/>` is specific to the .NET Framework and can only be configured in:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[framework version]\CONFIG\machine.config
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[framework version]\CONFIG\web.config
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[framework version]\CONFIG\machine.config
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[framework version]\CONFIG\web.config
```

and of course your application's `app.config` or `web.config` files.

My advice would be to keep these settings local to your application unless there is the rare occasion where you need some value to be available globally.

*Update:*

Now that I understand your problem - you have multiple IIS sites which all point to the same physical folder - there is a way to approach this.

You could have a configuration table in your database that has a primary key of whatever the `HTTP_HOST` value is. This maps to a prefix, for example:

```
Host               SitePrefix
====               ======
domain1.com        D001
domain2.com        D002
```

In your `web.config`:

In your application's `Application_Start` event in `Global.asax.cs` initialise an application wide value:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    string httpHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
    Application["SitePrefix"] = GetSiteKeyFromDb(httpHost);
}
```

This value will be available across the whole application but unique to the site.

When you need to read a setting that is specific to the site:

```
string siteSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
    HttpContext.Current.Application["SitePrefix"] + "_Setting1"
];
```

But if you're hitting the database in `Application_Start` then it may actually be expedient to store all these site specific settings in the database then read and cache them in `Application` instead of using `<appSettings />`.

Comment: You're probably right... though it didn't give any errors when I put <appSettings> under that location.  As to the specifics... it has to do with using a single physical path to host multiple virtual hosts.  The short and unfortunate answer is that while you may be able to reuse your code, you're still left with a single configuration and *you* must drive your answer off the HTTP_HOST.  I was trying to avoid writing code to handle host-specific configuration since that was precisely what IIS was doing.  Oh well, live and learn.

Comment: @ajaxx - when you say multiple virtual hosts do you mean a single site with multiple host headers or multiple sites pointing at the same physical folder?

Comment: Multiple sites on the same physical host all pointing at the same physical folder.  It's an asp.net site and almost everything is data driven.  There's really no reason do duplicate the deployed resources so we didn't.  The only caveat was that we were hoping to be able to have site-based configuration - instead it's based on physical path (web.config).  We'll just work around it by relying on server variables to make some key decisions.

Comment: Thanks for the update Kev.  This is essentially the same place we landed, which is that configuration must be driven by the HTTP_HOST.

Answer (score 1):

I used the information provided by [Anti-Santa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/the-anti-santa)'s answer to accomplish this but I didn't want to parse the URL and have another database to look up information.  The same codebase is used on-premise and I wouldn't have those pieces in that scenario.

Just add the `appSettings` to the .NET Framework `web.config` with a `location` node.

In `%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[framework version]\Config\web.config`, add the following where `Site1` and `Site2` are my two applications pointing to the same physical directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the root web configuration file -->
<configuration>

    <!-- App settings for the different applications -->
    <location path="Default Web Site/Site1">
        <appSettings>
            <add key="ConnectionString" value="the cnn str"/>
        </appSettings>
    </location>
    <location path="Default Web Site/Site2">
        <appSettings>
            <add key="ConnectionString" value="the cnn str"/>
        </appSettings>
    </location>

...

</configuration>
```

The `web.config` in the physical folder will override this `appSetting` so I also needed to remove it from that file.